# Grouping list of dates by year, using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

Could you help me? I have XML:

```
<root>
  <prop>
    <holidays>2011-01-01</holidays>
    <holidays>2011-01-02</holidays>
  ...
    <holidays>2012-01-01</holidays>
    <holidays>2012-01-02</holidays>
  ...
  </prop>
</root>
```

I need to get the following JSON from it:

```
[
{
"id" : "2011",
"data" : 
[
"2011-01-01","2011-01-02" ...
]
},
{
"id" : "2012",
"data" : 
[
"2012-01-01","2012-01-02" ...
]
},
...
]
```

With XSLT transformation 1.0

Thank you in Advance for your help!

UPDATE: Here is a solution that suited me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:key name="group" match="prop/holidays" use="substring-before(string(.),'-')"/>
<xsl:template match="root">[
<xsl:apply-templates select="prop/holidays[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('group',substring-before(string(.),'-')))]" />]</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="holidays">{
"id" : "<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(string(.),'-')"/>",
"data" : 
[
<xsl:for-each select="key('group',substring-before(string(.),'-'))">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>",</xsl:for-each>
]
},
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm new here, sorry I didn't say Hello)

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Note that what you show is not valid JSON.